# Can I configure my apple remote with custom keys/functions?

Tags: remote-control, mapping

I would like to press the <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> button on my apple remote, and "virtually" make the mac think I pressed the left arrow <kbd>←</kbd> or the right arrow <kbd>→</kbd> key.

Is there a free application for that?

```
I've found:
```

http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/

http://mira.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: lol, wait... you still use MS DOS... in a mac?! :-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great, I've found [iRedLite](http://www.filewell.com/iRedLite/)! I can create my own mappings (they are called layers in iRedLite) with this. :)

And here some other [great tips](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/04/19/10-ways-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-apple-remote/)... (old post, but a good reference!)

Comment: Did you happen to stumble upon my [new issue](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127765/how-to-configure-my-apple-remote-with-custom-actions-including-sleep-wake-up) arised from this scenario, and found a solution? :P