# How to configure my apple remote with custom actions, including sleep & wake up?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, macos

This is basically a follow up of [MSDOS's question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26900/can-i-configure-my-apple-remote-with-custom-keys-functions/26901#26901). I've also came around [same things](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/04/19/10-ways-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-apple-remote/) he did and I am currently using [iRedLite](http://www.filewell.com/iRedLite/) with great success. It is in almost all aspects even better than the already awesome RemoteBuddy - except it doesn't grab the process as good as.

Any way, I've figured [an simple way to put the *display* to sleep with apple script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284586/274502) and easily assigned it to holding the play button. And it works...

*Except* that it also crashes iRedLite. I think it enters in a dead loop or something and it just stop responding. But I believe even if it didn't crash, it still wouldn't work to wake up the display. That is because even if I enter sleep using CTRL+SHIFT+EJECT, I can't use the remote to wake up (when iRedLite didn't crash).

Meanwhile if I simply turn off iRedLite, I can put it to sleep and / or awake using any combinations with the keyboard shortcut or remote buttons. Holding the Play button is the default behaviour to put display to sleep.